# Using Modeshape 3.3 with JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, modeshape

Are there anyone who manage to configure Modeshape in JBoss 7.1.1?
I am following the guide on the link below but after I unzipped the files to the server and restarted and try to exectue this command:

```
/extension=org.modeshape:add()
```

I get:

```
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException: Error loading module from C:\\Users\\Test\\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\\modules\\org\\mo
deshape\\jcr\\api\\main\\module.xml",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODE/Configuring+ModeShape+in+AS7

Answer (score 0):

JBoss AS7.1 is the last public release of the JBoss AS project and is about 2 years old. It has been superseded by EAP 6.1, which is based off of the JBoss AS project but is more recent and is supported. EAP 6.1 is far more stable, and for ModeShape is a far better runtime platform. This is why ModeShape 3.3 only runs in EAP 6.1.

(JBoss AS7.1 is simply too old and has several critical issues in the libraries that ModeShape uses. This is why newer releases of ModeShape no longer deploy on top of AS7.1.)

See our [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODE/ModeShape+and+JBoss+AS7+or+EAP) and [blog post](http://modeshape.wordpress.com/2013/04/22/modeshape-3-2-and-jboss-eap/) for details about the switch and how you can use EAP.